# red free support for images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a web application for a opthology research firm. They work on cornea images and use red free light to identify lesions (artries and nerve fibers) easily. I have implemented the addAmbient() method provided by microsoft for this purpose and it is working fine.
`<img id="eyepic" src="GetImage.jsp" height="1291" width="1944" STYLE="filter:light" onload="eyepic.filters.light.addAmbient(0,255,255,100)">`

But the problem is this thing works only in IE. I am looking for a method to implement this for other browsers too. If anyone has any idea please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Not knowing off the top of my head what `eyepic.filters.light.addAmbient` does, could you describe what needs to be done to the image?

Comment: What is "red free light"? Best post an example.

Comment: Can't you just add the light at server side (GetImage.jsp)?

Answer (score 0):

hey everyone thanks for responding.Actually i slved my problem a month ago,just forgot to update it here.I am now using java2D api for creating redfree images.It has BandCombineOp to manipulate pixels.
Thanks anyway